# Spring security not able to find login url

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have an existing web application. I am trying to integrate spring security with it. Something is wrong I the login url of spring security is not recognised after my application is deployed i can see no errors

> org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain  Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@71cc932, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@71d35b4, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@71d1f86, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@71d08b7, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@71d4ca2, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@71ceaed, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@71d4047, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@71cd7f9, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@71cfc0f, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@71d2ae9, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@71d141a, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@71d5b32]

When I trying to login I am getting this

> File not found: /j_spring_security_check
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor._processEDR(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:893)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.processEDR(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:874)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:434)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:926)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1023)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3703)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:962)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:276)
>       at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
>       at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
>       at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
>       at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1659)

The Config file

```
    @Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemp;

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("SecurityConfig.configAuthentication() - START");
      auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(jdbcTemp.getDataSource())
        .usersByUsernameQuery(
            "select id,pwd,'true' as enabled from scm_users where id=?")
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
            "select id, 'default' from scm_users where id=?");
    }   

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
        .and()
          .formLogin().loginPage("/userLogin.htm").failureUrl("/userLogin.htm?error")
          .usernameParameter("id").passwordParameter("pwd")
        .and()
          .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/userLogin.htm?logout")
        .and()
          .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
        .and()
          .csrf();
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
    <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/pages/PageNotFound.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

in my spring-servlet, which is in web-inf folder. I don not have any application context so pointed to spring-servlet.xml. Is that correct.

Spring-servlet.xml

```
    <?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"........

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.ibm.idea.scm.*" />


    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="mediaTypes">
          <map>
            <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
          </map>
        </property>
        <property name="viewResolvers">
          <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
              <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
               <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
               <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
            </bean>
          </list>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultViews">
          <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
              <property name="prefixJson" value="true"/>
            </bean>
          </list>
        </property>
    </bean>


   <bean id="portalDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="SCMDB" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="portalCRMDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="CRMDB"/>
    </bean> 

 <!-- 
    <bean id="portalDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="jndi/SCMDB" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="portalCRMDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
             <property name="jndiName" value="jndi/CRMDB"/>
     </bean> -->


    <bean id="jdbcTemp" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="portalDataSource" />
    </bean>
       <bean id="jdbcTempCRM" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
          <property name="dataSource"  ref="portalCRMDataSource" />    
       </bean>
    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />  
</beans>
```

The login jsp form

```html
<form class="loginInput" class="col-md-4" action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />" method="post">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-12">
        <p>
         <b>Sign In</b>
        </p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-12">
        <input type="text" placeholder="User Name" name="id" class="form-control">
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-12">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pwd" class="form-control">
       </div>
```

Please point out the mistake

### Regards

Adeeb

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related with Websphere Web Container. Please follow the following instructions

This information is available elsewhere, but to minimize the misery for anyone viewing this thread, the issue can be resolved as follows:

1. WAS must be at fixpack 6.1.0.11 or higher.
2. A custom property must be set on the web container so WAS will play nicely with filters that decide to commit a response instead of passing responsibility along to the next filter in the chain. com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokefilterscompatibility = true

More info on the bug and the fix available here:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24014758

Set this property in the WebSphere admin console using directions available here:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rss=180&uid=swg21284395

[Source](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/43980-spring-security-2-not-working-with-websphere).

Comment: It did not help, still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is replace your `loginPage("/userLogin.htm")` by the `RequestMapping` that you had set in controller.

Hope it help.

**EDIT**

Try to add this in your xml config file:

```
<beans>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <bean class="your.package.SecurityConfig"/>
</beans>
```

For more detail go to [here](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.0.0.M2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html).

Comment: When I do that it does not invoke the security filter anymore, I have xml and annotation based config. Annotation based config for just spring security. I think I am missing the part to invoke the security config. Dont know exactly

Comment: I think its loading the spring config class as I could see the print statements in the log. I will update complete exception in question

Answer (score 0):

Replace this -> `<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />" method="post">`

with -> `<c:url value='/YourAppName/j_spring_security_check' />" method="post">`